Is there a way to refine 3d camera track created by lidar?
There are some wonderful apps that can capture 3d camera tracking data using the Iphone's lidar sensor. However occasionally there is jitter or sliding in these camera tracks.
So, In the scene I have camera, background video and lidar scanned 3d scene. (no tracking points)
I was wondering if there is a way to refine the imported 3d camera track using the background video and the readily available accurate 3d scan of the scene.
(If only I could click some points in the background video and corresponding points in the 3d scan and say the camera keep the overall 3d track but fix it so these points do not move away from each other)
